# Add this registry value to windows

Tags: batch-file, registry

I want to create a batch file that will create a value set to 0 in the registry. This is because of the print nightmare issue so I can do this in several computers in the business...

```
Location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print
DWORD (32 bit) value RpcAuthnLevelPrivacyEnabled
Value data 0
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print" /v RpcAuthnLevelPrivacyEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Comment: In a batch file should be used the fully qualified file name of the [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) __REG__ which is `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe`. But the command line is correct. Hint for readers interested in this command line: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window, run `reg /?` and read the output help, next run `reg add /?` and read again the output help for more information about this command line.